# Regarding Storing file path in set STL in c++

Tags: c++, stl, directory, set

I want to store directories and the files contained in them. But I am not able to use `insert` function for the `SET STL`. I want to ignore duplicate directories which will come because of multiple files in the same location. Below is the code snippet. I am getting error at insert function.

```
   using path_1 = std::string; 
    using paths_1 = std::set <path_1>;
```

---

```
 void search()
  { 
      for (recursive_directory_iterator i("."), end; i != end; ++i)
      {
       if (!is_directory(i->path()))
       {

        paths_1.insert(i->path().parent_path());
        std::cout << i->path().parent_path() << "\n";
       }
        if (!is_directory(i->path()))
       {
        files.push_back(i->path().filename());
        // std::cout << i->path().filename() << "\n";

       }

      }

      for (auto f : files)
      {
       store_.save(f);
      }
}
```

Comment: How about posting *what* the error message is, along with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)? `paths_1.insert(...)` `paths_1` is a type, an alias for `set<string>`, you need to insert the paths into an *instance* of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to *have* a `std::set`, Something like:

paths_1 my_paths;

then you work with that instance (*not* the type itself):

```
my_paths.insert(i->path().parent_path());
```